# Using RegExp to find words with escape characters

Tags: regex

How can i make regexp to find words begining with escape character \

I want to find words like `\wek \md \wkeo \wema`
I tried `\b\\\w+` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Escape the escape character. What tool/language are you using?

Comment: How it doesn't worked? whats you regex engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\B\\\w+/g
```

Problem is presence of `\b` in your regex `/\b\\\w+/`. You **cannot use `\b` before `\` since `\` is not a word character.**

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT5gW8/9)